# Can't require a clj ns in a cljs file

Tags: clojure, macros, clojurescript

I have an myapp.environment namespace like so in an environment.clj file.

```
(ns myapp.environment
  (:require  [myapp.config :refer [env]]))
(defmacro myapp-url [] (:myapp-url env))
```

Then I require this in an events.cljs file like
`[myapp.environment :refer-macros [myapp-url]]`
I get the error

```
The required namespace "myapp.environment" is not available, it was required by "myapp/events.cljs".
"myapp/environment.clj" was found on the classpath. Should this be a .cljs file?
```

when using it like so:

```
(http/get (str (myapp-url) "/somepath"))
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: well, because you can't, i guess. you can require `cljs` or `cljc`, or refer macros from `clj` with `:require-macros`. more differences [here](https://clojurescript.org/about/differences#_macros)

Comment: so the easiest way to fix it, is to make your `myapp.config` a `.cljc` file, i guess, and check that your clojure/clojurescript specific code is under [reader conritionals](https://clojure.org/guides/reader_conditionals) there

Comment: Here's a simple example of a "general purpose" namespace that can be used from both Clojure and ClojureScript, including reader conditionals on the `ns` (requires) section: https://github.com/borkdude/advent-of-cljc/blob/master/src/aoc/utils.cljc